# Using shell, how to skip to next element in a for loop?

Tags: linux, shell

Here's what my script should do: it pings 5 times the IP address of each line of an imported text file. If the IP is unreachable 3 of the 5 times, it echo "it's down!" and (should) move on to the next IP... Except I don't know how to configure this "skip" part.
Here is my current code:

```sh
FILE=file.txt
unreachableIP=0

while IFS='' read -r line || [ -n "$line" ]; do
    set -- $line

    for (( i=1; i<=5; i++ ))
    do
        echo "Ping $1 $i times"
        ping -c 1 $1
        if [ "$?" = 0 ]
        then
            echo "reachable"
        else
            echo "unreachable"
            ((unreachableIP++))
            echo $unreachableIP
            if [ $unreachableIP -eq 3 ]
            then
                echo "it's down!"
                unreachableIP=0
            fi
        fi
    done
done < $FILE
```

Example: if the IP address is reachable 1st time, unreachable 2nd time, unreachable 3rd time and unreachable 4th time, I want the script to move to the next IP (next line) and not try to ping a 5th time.
Here is the `file.txt`:

```
8.8.8.8 GoogleDNS
1.1.1.1 CloudFlareDNS
213.1.1.1 SomeFakeIPForDebug
```

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: I don't want to use break because it will stop pinging the other IPs too... and I would like it to only stop pinging the current IP.

Comment: Use `read -r ip line`; then you don't need to use `set` at all, instead using `$ip` in place of `$1`.

Answer (score 5):

continue

> The break and continue loop control commands [1] correspond exactly to their >counterparts in other programming languages. The break command terminates the loop >(breaks out of it), while continue causes a jump to the next iteration of the loop, >skipping all the remaining commands in that particular loop cycle.

see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/loopcontrol.html

Comment: As far as I understand, it's about breaking a loop, not "skipping the current occurence".

Comment: Yes that is right, I answered the question and did not provide a solution for the code

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` to achieve the "skip" feature you're talking about.

For example

```sh
if [ "$unreachableIP" -eq 3 ]; then
   break
fi
```

It will exit the current loop.

Comment: If I use break, it will indeed exit the loop and then not ping the other IPs... I want it to keep pinging the other IPs.

Comment: @a_v_e_ `break` should only break out of the inner for loop, not the outer while loop.

Comment: @a_v_e_ `break` will only break the **current** loop, so that the `while` loop will still be continued